# Rotating a rectangle containing image pixel data to vertical to perform image processing operation

Tags: java, image-processing

I have created an image processing application that allows me to click two points in an image. I then use different algorithms to find the co ordinates of the path connecting the two points.

Then each pixel is used to find a target pixel 10 pixels away at a 90 degree angle in both directions. The result is that I then have a two dimensional array of pixel values which can be used to create a sub image for processing.

I need the new image to be vertical to enable me to carry out some image processing manipulation. Should I create a new `BufferedImage` from these pixel values and then process that by rotating it to the vertical or can I rotate the 2D array of values I already have? to be honest I have seen so many examples of Affine Transform I'm not sure what approach would be best.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the new image to be vertical" and why is this a constraint on the processing?

Comment: The images are of blood vessels and i need the image to be horizontal (sorry my mistake on vertical) to enable me to travel across the image and calculate the widths of the vessel.

Comment: Maybe some image examples may help users get a grasp on what you are asking.  My initial though would be to have the image processing algorithm just traverse the image in the desired direction. If you need to rotate it, affine transforms are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks I'm sorry I wasn't very clear. You were right the easiest way was to traverse the line at + and - 90 degree angles and store the data in an array. Thanks for the help and I'll be sure to post some code next time.